# What is returned from DBMS_SQL.varchar2s.COUNT?

Tags: plsql, oracle11g

I find when googled that `DBMS_SQL.varchar2s`is Table. That got me into more confusion as Table.COUNT does not seem to make any sense.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Not actually, it is defined as:

```
 type varchar2s is table of varchar2(256) index by binary_integer;
```

But "table of ..." makes it a plsql collection and not a database table. Two completely different usages of the word "table" When you use it's the same as any other variable so:

```
declare 
    some_collection  dbms_sql.varchar2s;
```

The `COUNT` then is a property indicating the number of rows (or enteries) the collection contains.

And would be used for the above declaration as `some_collection.count`. 
For example:

```
for collection_index in 1 .. some_collection.count
loop 
    .
    .
    .
end loop;
```

I hope his clears it up for you.